# How to extract only record in a certain period in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am having problems with extracting records belonging to a certain period. Specifically I have an ORDER field that is a VARCHAR2 in the form DD-MON-RR (I know the varchar2 datatype is not good but I can't change it) and what I want is to exclude those records that have Saturday as their weekly day. Also I want to extract all records from the last 30 days. How to do this? I am having the error 'Not a valid month'.

For example I have:

```
01-GEN-24  
06-GEN-24
```

My output must be only : 01-GEN-24

For the moment i have done this query

```
    SELECT order
FROM my_table
WHERE TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(SUBSTR(order, 1, 9), 'DD-MON-RR'), 'D') <> '7';
```

but it is wrong.

Comment: `GEN` is indeed not a valid month in English. How did you set up your locale/NLS parameters?

Comment: I have set my param in ITALIAN

Comment: Your TO_DATE needs to be the first function (innermost, direclty around the column). Don't try to use SUBSTR at all. Thereis no need to try to get rid of the time portion (dates *always* have a time portion. just ignore it if you don't need it). Once that is a real date, it can then be passed to TO_CHAR as you're already doing to emit the day-of-the-week.

Comment: even if i do SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(order, 'DD-MON-YY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ITALIAN'), 'DD-MON-YY')
FROM my_table; it gives me not a valid month error

Comment: Then you have invalid dates in your table.

Answer (score 1):

Compare your date with the start of the ISO week (which is always midnight Monday) and specify the NLS settings for the conversion when you use `TO_DATE` with language specific options.

```sql
SELECT "ORDER"
FROM   my_table
WHERE  TO_DATE(SUBSTR("ORDER", 1, 9), 'DD-MON-RR', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=Italian')
       - TRUNC(
         TO_DATE(SUBSTR("ORDER", 1, 9), 'DD-MON-RR', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=Italian'),
         'IW'
       ) != 5 -- Saturday
       ;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_table ("ORDER") AS
  SELECT '01-GEN-24' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '06-GEN-24' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ORDER |
| --- |
| 01-GEN-24 |

If you want to also filter within the last 30 days then compare to `SYSDATE`:

```sql
SELECT "ORDER"
FROM   my_table
WHERE  TO_DATE(SUBSTR("ORDER", 1, 9), 'DD-MON-RR', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=Italian')
       - TRUNC(
         TO_DATE(SUBSTR("ORDER", 1, 9), 'DD-MON-RR', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=Italian'),
         'IW'
       ) != 5 -- Saturday
AND    TO_DATE(SUBSTR("ORDER", 1, 9), 'DD-MON-RR', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=Italian')
       >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - INTERVAL '30' DAY;
```

Which does not match any rows as 1st January is more than 30 days ago.

---

*Note: You could use `TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(SUBSTR(order, 1, 9), 'DD-MON-RR', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=Italian'), 'D')` to find the day of the week but the output depends on the user's `NLS_TERRITORY` setting so different users may get different outputs depending on where in the world their configuration is set to. Comparing to the beginning of the ISO week is independent of all these settings so will work consistently everywhere in the world.*

For example:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TERRITORY = 'Italy';
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = 'Italian';

SELECT "ORDER",
       TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(SUBSTR("ORDER", 1, 9), 'DD-MON-RR', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=Italian'), 'D') As to_char_d_day,
       TO_DATE(SUBSTR("ORDER", 1, 9), 'DD-MON-RR', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=Italian') - TRUNC(TO_DATE(SUBSTR("ORDER", 1, 9), 'DD-MON-RR', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=Italian'), 'IW') AS iso_week_day
FROM   my_table;
```

Outputs:

| ORDER | TO_CHAR_D_DAY | ISO_WEEK_DAY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01-GEN-24 | 1 | 0 |
| 06-GEN-24 | 6 | 5 |

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TERRITORY = 'America';
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = 'Italian';
SELECT "ORDER",
       TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(SUBSTR("ORDER", 1, 9), 'DD-MON-RR', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=Italian'), 'D') As to_char_d_day,
       TO_DATE(SUBSTR("ORDER", 1, 9), 'DD-MON-RR', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=Italian') - TRUNC(TO_DATE(SUBSTR("ORDER", 1, 9), 'DD-MON-RR', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=Italian'), 'IW') AS iso_week_day
FROM   my_table;
```

Outputs:

| ORDER | TO_CHAR_D_DAY | ISO_WEEK_DAY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01-GEN-24 | 2 | 0 |
| 06-GEN-24 | 7 | 5 |

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TERRITORY = 'Bangladesh';
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = 'Italian';
SELECT "ORDER",
       TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(SUBSTR("ORDER", 1, 9), 'DD-MON-RR', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=Italian'), 'D') As to_char_d_day,
       TO_DATE(SUBSTR("ORDER", 1, 9), 'DD-MON-RR', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=Italian') - TRUNC(TO_DATE(SUBSTR("ORDER", 1, 9), 'DD-MON-RR', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=Italian'), 'IW') AS iso_week_day
FROM   my_table;
```

Outputs:

| ORDER | TO_CHAR_D_DAY | ISO_WEEK_DAY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01-GEN-24 | 4 | 0 |
| 06-GEN-24 | 2 | 5 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Q0lrmYL2)

Comment: I have tried SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(SUBSTR(order, 1, 9), 'DD-MON-RR', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=Italian'), 'D')
FROM my_table; and it doesn't works. I have seen that my nls_territoy is Italy, my NLS_LANGUAGE is Italian and my NLS_DATE_FORMAT is 'DD-MON-RR'. I have still not a valid month error

Comment: @Mariomaxi "it doesn't works" is not a constructive statement as it does not tell us what does not work nor what the error is. Without more details it is difficult to help but the most common error is that your string is not a valid date. If you are using Oracle 12 or later then you can use `TO_DATE(SUBSTR("ORDER", 1, 9) DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR, 'DD-MON-RR', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=Italian')`.